# An algorithm for locating candidate labelling boxes within a polygon

Tags: postgis, algorithm

Has anyone implemented [this algorithm](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmapcontext.com%2Fautocarto%2Fproceedings%2Fauto-carto-8%2Fpdf%2Fpages700-711.pdf&ei=2yyZUaCDJuj2iwKSkIHYCA&usg=AFQjCNHuorXA_b-u9kCzNDyxcQd8rJBigQ&sig2=GNz2kOgHW1v6DV-IvlmLew) In PostGIS? Quoting from the paper:

> *Vector-based geographic information systems usually require annotation, such as a polygon number or attribute data, in a suitable
>   location within a polygon. Traditional methods usually compute the
>   polygon centroid, test the centroid for inclusion or exclusion, and
>   select some alternative point when the centroid falls outside the
>   polygon. Two problems are associated with this approach:(1) the text
>   can be centered on the point, but may be placed in a visually awkward
>   place, and (2) part of the text may fall outside the polygon and may
>   overlap other polygon boundaries or other text labels. An algorithm is
>   presented that circumvents both of these problems, by computing a
>   number of horizontal candidate labelling rectangles (boxes) within a
>   polygon from which a suitable selection can be made or from which one
>   may conclude that the text label does not fit the polygon.*

Perhaps in a custom build, or as a combination of several `ST_` functions? Even a command line utility?